# Changes in the code or the designer won't update when debugging

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging

I am trying to debug my VB.net app in Visual Studio Express 2010, when I realized my changes will not update on my form-on the designer or in the code. After looking online, I found that you should clear out the "Debug" folder under the bin. That worked-for only one time. Now it went back to the older version and when I delete it again, it doesn't change. When I build the project and run it from the "Release" folder, it works perfectly, but when a error occurs at runtime, it won't show where the error is because it is running independently.

Thanks in advance.

(I have Windows XP SP3)

Comment: mmm... if it was for me, with such a weird bug, i would create a new project then insert the files (not as a link, but a copy) in the project, and i most likely all will work fine after... Faster than finding where-the-hell is that wrong parameter...

Comment: @VincentPiel thanks for your quick reply. I will try that and let you know. Can you put that as an awnser below so I can accept it please?

Comment: How do you do that? I went to try and realized that I didn't know what I was doing.

Comment: @VincentPiel **UPDATE:** This is just happening in one form not both I think I'll try Yatrix's solution.

Comment: @Yatrix (Look at the post above - I needed to alert two people at the same time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I'd create a new project, I'd copy all of the code-behind (including the code that creates the controls that you're not supposed to touch) into another form. That may be all you need to do. Try compiling that form and running it and see if it's good. If so, you won't have to create a whole new project and can just delete the old form.

I would think there's something causing this that would be much easier to to fix. Are there any config files or anything like that? Are you building to the right location?

It's been a while since I've done winforms, but I remember this happening in VS 2005 and I just created a new form and copied the code-behind into another winform and compiled.

Hope this helps.

Comment: it automaticly builds to the spot in the project folder where the files are and I look where I open the project file under Bin>Debug and Bin>Release (Debug for IDE, Release for when exporting project...) I don't know what a Config file is - or at least I can't find anything like that. What is the file extention of a Config FIle

Comment: Thank you so much it worked perfectly and it updates plus I didn't lose anything and it was easy-well I forgot to copy the actual code (luckly I had only one sub the rest of my hard work was in the designer.) **For people with same error-In solution explore click Show all files - it's a icon up top and the expand the form that doesn't work. Then rename the form that doesn't work to something like MyForm1 if it was MyForm and then add a new form named MyForm and then copy over the code (the code you wrote) and do the same for the MyForm1.Designer.vb from old to new files**

Comment: **I didn't have to do the .resx file because it just had settings for where the My timer control was placed on the bottem - but check it and look around it. If the new one doesn't have it or the old one- leave it alone. Then delete MyForm1 and click Show All Files again to remove the extra junk that you're not suppost to touch. Your done- make sure to change any code in other forms that mention MyForm- when you renamed it it went to MyForm1 (The old version which you deleted) and you deleted that so it should have a error and that will be easy to spot...**

Comment: @AnnonomusPerson Awesome. Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Frustrating problem....? Close the project, go to debug bin/folder, delete these files, reopen project and rebuild it (F5).
- .exe
- .pdb
- .vshost.exe
- .vshost.exe.manifest
- .xml

it works 99.99%.......thanks

Answer (score 1):

mmm... if it was for me, with such a weird bug, i would create a new project then insert the files (not as a link, but a copy) in the project, and i most likely all will work fine after... Faster than finding where-the-hell is that wrong parameter...
So how do you do that ? Well create a new project, choose the folder and name, change namespace in settings if needed, then in project explorer Add existing item, then Browse and select your code and xaml (and other maybe) files. Let us know.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me as well. I believe the `/bin` and `/obj` folders of my application must've been locked for by some other application. Before manually deleting them I tried running Visual Studio as an administrator and did a Clean and a Rebuild which worked. If it doesn't work for you, try deleting the folders manually.

Answer (score 0):

1. Close VS
2. Press *Ctrl + Alt + Delete*
3. Choose *"Task Manager"*
4. In the *"Process"* tab in *"Task Manager"* find your *"ProjectName.EXE"* and click *"End Task"*
5. Restart VS

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but i changed the solution config next to the start button from debug to release and that fixed my problem, try it :)

Answer (score 0):

"Save all" works for me in VS 2010 VB, in Debug and Release mode. 
I put the "Save all" icon next to the Run and Build icons.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your Localizable Property of you form is set to FALSE

[image: Localizable prop]